# Typescript Regex: filter is returning empty

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Im making a Ecommerce API, and i  have this class for my search queries, im using regex and typescript with node to achieve that, im using a js node project to base me, but the filter is retuning empty when i use "localhost:4000/api/products/?page=1":

```
export class APIFeatures {

    query: any;
    queryStr: any;

    constructor(query: any, queryStr: any) {
        this.query = query,
            this.queryStr = queryStr
    }

    search(): any {
        const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword ? {
            name: {
                $regex: this.queryStr.keyword,
                $options: 'i'
            }
        } : {}

        this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword })


    }


    filter(): any {

        const queryCopy = { ...this.queryStr };

        // Removing fields from the query
        const removeFields = ['keyword', 'limit', 'page']
        removeFields.forEach(el => delete queryCopy[el]);

        // Advance filter for price, ratings etc
        let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryCopy)
        queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g, match => `$${match}`)
        // console.log(queryStr)

        this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
        return this;
    }

    pagination(resPerPage: any): any {
        const currentPage = Number(this.queryStr.page) || 1;
        const skip = resPerPage * (currentPage - 1);

        this.query = this.query.limit(resPerPage).skip(skip);
        return this;
    }


}
```

this is the productController, where i wanna execute the serach, filter and pagination, to personalize the query from the product database:

```
 async getAllProducts(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {

            const resPerPage = 8;
            const productCount = await prisma.product.count();

            const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(prisma.product.findMany(), req.query)
                .search()
                .filter()
                .pagination(resPerPage)

            const response = apiFeatures.query;

            return res.status(200).send({ success: true, response, 
   productCount })
        } catch (error) {
            res.send({
                message: error
            })
        }
    }
```

the question is why my query is retuning empty

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: i changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fix your search() function like that, it should be fixed

```
search(): any {
        const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword ? {
            name: {
                $regex: this.queryStr.keyword,
                $options: 'i'
            }
        } : {}

        this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });

        return this;
    }
```